# Asp.net web, update a display as each record is looped through... 1 of X as records are loaded

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2012

I have a asp.net web application being written in VB which requires records to be uploaded from an external file. 
I want to be be able to update the user as each record is processed.  What is the best way to display something similar to

"Record 1 of 159 being processed.."

Then change it to "Record 2 of 159 being processed", etc etc.

I anticipate it might be an ajax update panel or something but I need a little help getting started on this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is complicated since each request to the server is independent of each other and each request only have one response. You will need a way to keep track of the process somehow (unique id) and allow other request to fetch the status of this process (this all depends on what the process do). It might be hard to give you a good answer without know more detail.

Comment: You need keep track of sended requests "159" and assign some "callback" for every requests where response is succesful "callback" function will add number to the amount of processed records. It need to be done on client side.